# python ignore one of my conditions in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I don't know if I missed something that has affected my conditions but I have done my best to find where the misunderstanding laid but unfortunately I have found nothing .
this is the problem that I am working on:

> Write a program that will calculate the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number.
>
> N! = 1 * 2 * 3 *  … * N
> examples:
>
> ```
> zeros(6) = 1
> # 6! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 = 720 --> 1 trailing zero
>
> zeros(12) = 2
> # 12! = 479001600 --> 2 trailing zeros
> ```

and this is my code:

```
def factorial(x):
  if x==1:
    return x 
  else:
    return x*factorial(x-1)

def zeros(n):
  list1= list(str(factorial(n)))
  list2 = list1[:]
  for numbers in list1:  
    if numbers!=0:
      list2.remove(numbers)
    else:
      list3=list2.copy()
      list4=list3[:]
      list_of_numbers_except_0 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
      for numbers2 in list3:
        for numbers_except_0 in list_of_numbers_except_0:
          if numbers2 ==numbers_except_0:
            list3.remove(list4[0])
            break     
  return len("".join(list4))

print(zeros(20))
```

I hoped that if the condition "numbers doesn't equal 0 " is false then python can switch to the "else(numbers  equal 0 ==true)" condition, but it didn't work .
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't remove from `list3` while you're iterating over it.

Comment: This seems way more complicated than necessary. Just iterate over the string in reverse until the character isn't `0`.

Comment: Or use a regular expression that matches `0*$`, and get the length of the match.

Comment: but what to do  if there is a zero inside the middle of the string?

Comment: you could `enumerate` the reversed string to get the index and the character, once the character is not `0` print the index and exit the loop

Comment: Since the loop stops at the first non-zero character, you'll never get to a zero in the middle.

Comment: @OussamaElManar Why do you need the zeros in the middle of the string, if there is a non-zero character between that/those zeros and the end of the number?

Comment: mr.barmar why do you think that the loop will stop and for mr.beruic i don't need zeros inside but the factorial number of 20 is 2432902008176640000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list1` is a list of strings, and comparing a string to an integer returns always `False`

The problem is asking you the number of **trailing** zeroes, why are you trying to count all of the zeros?

I would solve the problem like this:

```
def zeros(n):
    for i, n in enumerate(str(n)[::-1]):
        if n != "0":
            return i
    return 1 # case n = 0
```

The main trick of this code is reversing the string by slicing with a [negative step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works) `[::-1]`:

for example `"2580"[::-1]` is turned into `"0852"`

now the problem has turned into "count the number of starting zeros"

to solve this problem you can write a simple program like this:

```
def zeros(n):
    reversed = str(n)[::-1]
    count = 0
    for character in reversed:
        if character == "0":
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count
```

in my previous code i'm using the function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?#enumerate) to automatically get the index of the current character, but there is a little risk, if the number is just `0` my `for` loop doesn't work, that's why i need to `return 1` to cover this edge case

Comment: A very efficient answer. It would be worth you briefly explaining to the OP how this concise code works (string reversal, enumerate)

Comment: @Hoxha Alban thank you!! I am sure that one day  you will achieve your dreams.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the characters in the string representation of the number in reverse. When you get to a non-zero character, return the distance from the end.

```
def zeros(n):
    # degenerate case
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    n_string = str(n)
    for i in range(len(n_string) - 1, -1, -1):
        if n_string[i] != '0':
            return len(n_string) - i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to a string, just check how many times mod 10 is 0 (or conversely, the largest multiple of 10 that produces a modulus of 0).

```
def zeros(n):
  fn = factorial(n)))
  zero_cnt = 0
  while fn % 10 == 0:
    zero_cnt += 1
    fn = int(fn / 10) # / makes a float, convert back to int
  return zero_cnt
```

Comment: John Bayko , thank you ! I have over complicated my code due thinking differently